# Was my edit useful? How does it "deviate" the original intent?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I recently edited a question, I got an approval and a rejection with the reason "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post."

I don't understand exactly how the edit "deviates" the original intent. Could you help me understand if my edit was useless or wrong?

I made a similar change to another question before that no one rejected it.

First question without reject: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10629140

Second question with reject: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10629363

Comment: The intent was to ask a question, not to answer it.  These kind of "oops, silly mistake" questions are best deleted.  Too hard to do after this long.  You can always post the answer.

Comment: He said to me earlier that I should not change the question code (too much I think) and I should not include the answer in the question.

Here I included the answer of the OP in a comment below one of the answers

Comment: @HansPassant I thought about flagging it after the edit maybe... I wasn't sure how to proceed

Answer (score 7):

As I was the user who reviewed the post with a rejection, I'll try to explain. There was a number of issues with this edit.

First, most of the wording changes are only semantically different, or introduce punctuation; there was no improvement of grammar or spelling. Adding italics or quote marks is not an acceptable way to modify a user's post.

Second, changing the code to use double quotes, rather than single quotes, might seem not to be an issue, but sometimes it is the problem itself. How is the OP supposed to get an answer if someone has changed their code in the question, and that change was the problem?

Finally, **do not** include answers - even the OP's answer - in the question. If the OP has found a solution, then it's up to them to write an answer if they so wish.

Tidying up the HTML was fine, as was indenting the code for readability, but there were too many problems with this edit to accept it in my opinion. I could have chosen *Reject and Edit*, but the tidy up wasn't that pressing.

Comment: Well, I see your point of view. About the quotes here don't give any problems to the code, actually. I can understand the part about the inclusion of the answer to the question, but I believe the readability parts weren't bad. Probably with another edit (removing the answer) this could pass. Thanks for your time to help me understand this

Comment: "but there were too many problems with this edit to accept it in my opinion." reject and edit, reject *and edit*.

Comment: @Braiam With respect, that would still have led to this meta question.

Comment: No, because your intention would be made clear, since the reject and edit generates a message inviting he editor to check the post and since you addressed all the issues you noted on this answer, it would made clear to the editor that he should have do/do not.

Comment: @Braiam True, but the tidying edits I might have made were not essential. Indeed there were no critical issues that needed to be addressed in the post. That's the point of *reject and edit* is it not?

Comment: No, reject and edit is meant to say: the post was bad, but you didn't actually improved it.

Comment: @Braiam The post wasn't that bad.